# (java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference, onPostExecute in implimentaition of Json searchQuery

Tags: android, arrays, json, search, rotten-tomatoes

MyFragment

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            final View layoutSearch = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
            mswipeRefreshLayout=(SwipeRefreshLayout) layoutSearch.findViewById(R.id.searchMoviesRefresh);
           mswipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
            textVolleyError = (TextView) layoutSearch.findViewById(R.id.textVolleyError);
            listMovieHits = (RecyclerView) layoutSearch.findViewById(R.id.search_movies);
            listMovieHits.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            search=(SearchView) layoutSearch.findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
            search.setQueryHint("Start typing to search...");
            buttonBarcode = (ImageButton) layoutSearch.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
            buttonAudio = (ImageButton) layoutSearch.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    search.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        }
    });search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    L.t(getActivity(), newText);
                    if (newText.length() > 3) {
                        listMovieHits.setVisibility(layoutSearch.getVisibility());

                        searchForMovies m = (searchForMovies) new searchForMovies().execute(newText);
                    } else {
                        listMovieHits.setVisibility(layoutSearch.INVISIBLE);

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });


            listMovieHits.setAdapter(mAdapterBoxOffice);
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                mlistMovies = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(STATE_MOVIES);

            } else {
                L.t(getActivity(), "executing task from the fragment");
                /*new TaskLoadSearchMovies(this).execute();*/
            }


       /*     mAdapterBoxOffice.setMovieList(filteredProductResults);
            mAdapterBoxOffice.SetOnclickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    container.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(container.getContext(), Details_Activity.class));

                }
            });*/
            return layoutSearch;
        }
        public void filterProductArray(String newText){
            String sName;
            filteredProductResults.clear();
            for (int  i=0; i<mlistMovies.size(); i++)
            {
                sName=mlistMovies.get(i).getTitle().toLowerCase();
                if (sName.contains(newText.toLowerCase()))
                {
                filteredProductResults.add(mlistMovies.get(i));
            }
            }
        }
        class searchForMovies extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
        {
            Parser parser;
            JSONArray listMovies;
            String url=new String();
            String textSearch;
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){
                super.onPreExecute();
                listMovies=new JSONArray();
                parser =new Parser();
                progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Searching....");
                progressDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                progressDialog.show();
            }



            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                url="http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey={MyID}="+params+"limit=30";
                String returnMovieResult= getMovieList();
                this.textSearch=params[0];
                return returnMovieResult;

            }

            private String getMovieList() {
                Movie tempMovie=new Movie();
                String mathFound="N";
                try{
                    JSONObject response = Requestor.sendRequestBoxOfficeMovies(requestQueue, url);
                    ArrayList<Movie> listMovies = Parser.parseMoviesJSON(response);


    L.m(String.valueOf(listMovies));
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "error";
                }
                return ("Exception");
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("Exception Caught"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to connect to server,please try later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                else
                {


                    //calling this method to filter the search results from productResults and move them to
                    //filteredProductResults
                    filterProductArray(textSearch);
                    listMovieHits.setAdapter(mAdapterBoxOffice);
                    mAdapterBoxOffice.setFilteredMovies(mlistMovies);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

        }
```

AdapterClass

```
    public class AdapterBoxOffice extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterBoxOffice.ViewHolderBoxOffice> {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<Movie> mlistMovies = new ArrayList<>();
    private VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd");
    private  int previousPosition=0;
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    public  AdapterBoxOffice(Context context) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getsInstance();
        imageLoader = volleySingleton.getImageLoader();
    }

    public void setMovieList(ArrayList<Movie> listMovies) {
        this.mlistMovies = listMovies;

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setFilteredMovies(ArrayList<Movie> filteredProductResults){
        this.mlistMovies=filteredProductResults;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolderBoxOffice onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_movie_box_office, parent, false);
        ViewHolderBoxOffice viewHolder = new ViewHolderBoxOffice(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderBoxOffice holder, int position) {
        Movie currentMovie = mlistMovies.get(position);

        holder.movieTitle.setText(currentMovie.getTitle());
        Date movieReleaseDate = currentMovie.getReleaseDateTheater();
        if (movieReleaseDate != null) {
            String formmattedDate = dateFormat.format(movieReleaseDate);
            holder.movieReleaseDate.setText(formmattedDate);
        } else {
            holder.movieReleaseDate.setText(Constants.NA);

        }
        int audienceScore=currentMovie.getAudienceScore();
        if (audienceScore==-1){
            holder.movieAudienceScore.setRating(0.0F);
            holder.movieAudienceScore.setAlpha(0.5F);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.movieAudienceScore.setRating(currentMovie.getAudienceScore() / 20.0F);
            holder.movieAudienceScore.setAlpha(1.0F);
        }
        if(position>previousPosition)
        {
            comeagain.materialdesign.anim.AnimationUtils.animate(holder, true);

        }else {
            comeagain.materialdesign.anim.AnimationUtils.animate(holder, false);

        }
        previousPosition=position;

        String urlThumbnail = currentMovie.getUrlThumbnail();
        loadImages(urlThumbnail, holder);
    }

    private void loadImages(String urlThumbnail, final ViewHolderBoxOffice holder) {
        if (urlThumbnail != null) {
            imageLoader.get(urlThumbnail, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                    holder.movieThumbnail.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                }

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mlistMovies.size();
    }

     class ViewHolderBoxOffice extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private ImageView movieThumbnail;
        private TextView movieTitle;
        private TextView movieReleaseDate;
        private RatingBar movieAudienceScore;

        public ViewHolderBoxOffice(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            movieThumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieThumbnail);
            movieTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieTitle);
            movieReleaseDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieReleaseDate);
            movieAudienceScore = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieAudienceScore);
        }


}
```

LogCat

```
01-23 22:00:18.141 19563-19563/comeagain.materialdesign E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main


Process: comeagain.materialdesign, PID: 19563
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void comeagain.materialdesign.adapters.AdapterBoxOffice.setFilteredMovies(java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at comeagain.materialdesign.fragments.FragmentSearch$searchForMovies.onPostExecute(FragmentSearch.java:270)
                                                                          at comeagain.materialdesign.fragments.FragmentSearch$searchForMovies.onPostExecute(FragmentSearch.java:209)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I want to implement search query in Json Api, the problem is that the I am getting a null exception . I do not know why the filteredArray is returning null, I really do not know where is the problem, Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: mAdapterBoxOffice is null. I don't see any place in your code where you assign anything to it

Comment: Adapter is working fine. I have tested it, I did no post the whole code for adapter to avoid this post being too long..

Comment: can you post the code wherever you have created and used mAdapterBoxOffice?

Comment: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void comeagain.materialdesign.adapters.AdapterBoxOffice.setFilteredMovies(java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference" it means mAdapterBoxOffice is null. Either provide all the code that is concerned in your problem, or look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it as a possible duplicate

Comment: There it is, I have added the AdapterClass